# Django AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE imports improperly

Tags: django, upgrade

I've got two Django apps, one (running 1.4) with the following settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('appname.account',)
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'appname.account.UserProfile'
```

This works just fine. However, I have another app, that I'm porting to 1.4, which I have set the same (well, similar, they have different `appname`s) but which won't work due to a caught `ValueError` in the auth contrib package. I'm not sure where to begin looking for where to change this properly, any suggestions?

Comment: please post the full traceback

Answer (score 0):

Drop into the Python Django Shell, import your settings and verify that you really need appname prefix to load the Account model.